# Pandas df comparing two dates condition

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to add 1 if `date_` > `buy_date` larger than 12 months else 0

example df

```
customer_id   date_         buy_date
34555        2019-01-01    2017-02-01
24252        2019-01-01    2018-02-10
96477        2019-01-01    2017-02-18
```

output df

```
customer_id   date_         buy_date    buy_date>_than_12_months
34555        2019-01-01    2017-02-01    1
24252        2019-01-01    2018-02-10    0
96477        2019-01-01    2018-02-18    1
```

Answer (score 4):

Based on what I understand, you can try adding a year to `buy_date` and then subtract from `date_` , then check if days are + or -.

```
 df['buy_date>_than_12_months'] = ((df['date_'] - 
                               (df['buy_date']+pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=1)))
                                  .dt.days.gt(0).astype(int))
```

---

```
print(df)

   customer_id      date_   buy_date  buy_date>_than_12_months
0        34555 2019-01-01 2017-02-01                         1
1        24252 2019-01-01 2018-02-10                         0
2        96477 2019-01-01 2017-02-18                         1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

values = {'customer_id': [34555,24252,96477],
          'date_':  ['2019-01-01','2019-01-01','2019-01-01'],
          'buy_date':  ['2017-02-01','2018-02-10','2017-02-18'],
          }

df = pd.DataFrame(values, columns = ['customer_id', 'date_', 'buy_date'])

df['date_'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
df['buy_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['buy_date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')

print(df['date_'] - df['buy_date'])

df['buy_date>_than_12_months'] = pd.Series([1 if ((df['date_'] - df['buy_date'])[i]> np.timedelta64(1, 'Y')) else 0 for i in range(3)])
print (df)
```

Comment: By changing condition  `((df['date_'] - df['buy_date'])[i].days> 365 ` to           
`((df['date_'] - df['buy_date'])[i]> np.timedelta64(1, 'Y')) ` and thanks for logic.